# How can I mock Javascript file imported in Svelte for unit testing?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, svelte

I have the following svelte file

**Dashboard.svelte**

```
<script>
  import Proxy from "../Proxy.js";

  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  export let data = [];

  onMount(async () => {
    spinner = true;
    let data = await Proxy.getData();
  });
</script>
......
......
......
```

**Dashboard.test.js**

```
import Dashboard from "../src/Dashboard.svelte"
jest.mock("../src/Proxy.js");

describe('Dashboard Component', (next) => {
  it('should update data on mount', () => {
    const target = document.createElement('div');
    const dashboard = new Dashboard({ target });

    Proxy.getData.mockResolvedValue([{
        "id": "sdadasdas"
    }]);

    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(dashboard.data.length).toBe(1);
      next();
    }, 10);
  })
})
```

Now, it is not mocking the Proxy.js that I am trying to mock and always going into the inside code.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper way to handle this is like below:

```
import Proxy from "../src/Proxy.js";
import Dashboard from "../src/Dashboard.svelte"
jest.mock("../src/Proxy.js");

describe('Dashboard Component', (next) => {
  it('should update data on mount', () => {
    Proxy.mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            getData: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([{"id": "sdadasdas"}]);
        }
    });

    const target = document.createElement('div');
    const dashboard = new Dashboard({ target });

    // I don't know why using setTimeout here, but it's up to you !
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(dashboard.data.length).toBe(1);
      next();
    }, 10);
  })
});
```

Also if you need to mock the ***getData*** for another tests you could mock it with passing a second parameter to jest.mock like this:

```
jest.mock("../src/Proxy.js", () => {
    return {
        getData: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([{"id": "sdadasdas"}]);
    };
});
```

I am not aware of the context you are coding but I think another way to mock the ***getData*** is like below:

```
import Proxy from "../src/Proxy.js";
import Dashboard from "../src/Dashboard.svelte"
// Do not use automatic mock

describe('Dashboard Component', (next) => {
  it('should update data on mount', () => {
    Proxy.getData = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([{"id": "sdadasdas"}]);

    const target = document.createElement('div');
    const dashboard = new Dashboard({ target });

    // rest of the code ...
  })
});
```

Comment: Mocking somehow still not working. Tried out all ways but its not working for me. I think this is something to do with Svelte. But thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to mock `Proxy.js` before using it internally.

```
jest.mock("../src/Proxy.js");
import Dashboard from "../src/Dashboard.svelte"
```