# How do I mock a function inside an object with Jest & Typescript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, svelte

I have a function that will make a call to [`url`](https://github.com/roxiness/routify/blob/master/runtime/helpers.js#L206)

`index.svelte`

```
import {url} from '@roxi/routify';

someFunction(() => {
  let x = $url('/books') // need to mock this call
  console.log('x: ' + x);
});
```

How can I mock this line of code?

```
$url("/books")
```

[$ prefix](https://www.routify.dev/docs/helpers#url)

**Details:**

`url()` is an object that declares a named function `subscribe(listener)`

`subscribe(listener)` makes a call to the function `derived(...)`, which returns a `Readable` interface

`Readable` interface declares a different `subscribe(...)` function

**What I have tried:**

#1 `mockReturnValue` from `subscribe` inside `url`

```
import {readable} from "svelte/store";
import {mocked} from "jest-mock";
import {render} from "@testing-library/svelte";
import * as routify from "@roxi/routify";
import books_index from "./index.svelte";

jest.mock("@roxi/routify", jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    url: {
      subscribe: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(readable())
    }
  }
}));

const mockedRoutify = mocked(routify);

it("needs to work", () => {
  const results = render(books_index);
  expect(results);
});
```

Results in: `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'store_1' before initialization`

#2 `mockReturnValue` from `subscribe` inside `url`

```
jest.mock("@roxi/routify", jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    url: {
      subscribe: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => readable())
    }
  }
}));
```

Results in: `TypeError: $url is not a function`

**Other notes**

- I have tried [inside the test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69141153/404376), but then I get `routify_1.url.mockReturnValue is not a function`
- I have tried it with [`__esModules: true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61396377/404376) & without it.
- I have tried playing around with [where](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976644/404376) the `imports` & mock declarations are made.
- I do have another test with my own service working, so I am confident that my `jest.config.ts` and `tsconfig.json` is correct.

**Ask**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Svelte, but I guess you should mock this way

```
import * as routify from "@roxi/routify";

//you can return whatever you want in this mocked function
jest.spy(routify, 'url').mockReturnValue({
   subscribe: jest.fn()
})
```

One thing you need to keep in mind. This one will help you to override the original function (in this case, it's `url`) which means you won't have other attributes/functions in `url` except `subscribe`

Comment: So that results in `Error: Cannot spy the url property because it is not a function; object given instead`. And when I change that to `jest.spyOn(routify.url, 'subscribe').mockReturnValue(jest.fn());`, then I get `$url is not a function`. I suspect the issue is because the underlying lib returns a function wrapped inside an object.

Comment: Once you inspect that package, which value (or value type) has been presented for `url`?

Comment: hmm it's an object too, but I think you tried and the error told it's not an object :(